# How to write - If Visible selector?

Tags: if-statement, opacity, fadein, visible

Not sure how to write this;

If .sub1 is visible, .homepage fadeTo .25

Sub1 has a FadeIn and I want the homepage opacity to drop to .25 if the sub1 is open?

I have this;

```
 $("#cat").click(function(){
 if ($('.sub1').is(':visible') ) {
 $(".homepage").fadeTo(500, .25);}

 else {
 $(".homepage").fadeTo(500, 1);

 }
```

The actual website I am making > [Website Mockup](http://www.mediafire.com/file/rzg2h6423m42pw9/Dreambay.zip) > Clicking Categories fades in the sub menu and makes homepage opacity 25%,  clicking categories again, makes submenu fade Out making homepage 100%.....But clicking categories > Fashion > Mens Fashion > Smart, Brings up 'Mens Smart Fashion div" but clicking categories again fades the Mens Smart fashion div out, and brings .sub1 back, but the .homepage is 100% and not 25% when the .sub1 is open

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the visible `.sub1` and check the length, this may not be so great if there are multiple `.sub1's`, maybe add a little specificity to the selector.

This technique will filter out elements with css `visibility:hidden` or `opacity: 0` for the first `.sub1` (`':eq(0)'`). If the length is 0 the condition will return false.

```
if($('.sub1:eq(0):visible').length) {
    //.homepage fade to .25
}
```

Revised:

```
$("#cat").click(function(){
    if ($('.sub1').css('opacity') == .25 ) {  

        $('.homepage').fadeTo(500, 1);

    } else {

        $('.homepage').fadeTo(500, .25); 
    }
});
```

I think the reason the it would not fade back in is because your condition was checking for opacicty:0 which you never reached when fading to .25. You should set the condition to check a number `.25` to avoid checking multiple strings such as `'.25'` or `'0.25'`. Firefox reports `'0.25'`.

Comment: Hey tellez thanks for getting back, it's not regarding the length of the .sub1 div, its purely if the .sub1 div is visible, I want the homepage to drop to 0.25, and if the .sub1 is hidden then I want then .homepage back at 100%,

I have just written this;

 $("#cat").click(function(){
  if ($('.sub1').is(':visible') ) {
  $(".homepage").fadeTo(500, .25);}
 
  else {
  $(".homepage").fadeTo(500, 1);
  
  }
  
 });

Which seems to work partially, but doesn't bring the homepage back to 100%

Comment: Hi tellez, thanks again for for input, the homepage is set to 100% on load of the site, but when clicked on #cat the .sub1 div opens and this is when I want the homepage to go to 25%, to complicate the situation even more, there are products within the .sub1, and when clicked on these, the .homepage fades out and the product pages fadeIn, but if I were to open a product page and click on #cat again, the homepage is set to 100% again, this is why I wanted the .homepage opacity to be controlled whether the sub1 menu is visible or hidden.

Comment: This should meet the first part of what you are looking for. If you click on the #cat after loading the page the .hoempage will fadeTo 25%. The second part confuses me a little.

Comment: Testing this on the jquery site with firebug it appears to toggle the fade.

Comment: I'm not sure what firebug is, I'm a novice to Jquery so all this is new to me, Basically when .sub1 is visible, fade homepage to 25%, when .sub1 is hidden, bring homepage opacity back to 100%

the .sub1 is hidden via Jquery, not CSS would this have any effect, it doesn't seem to work for me, I'm using Safari 5.1, the homepage doesn't come back to 100%

Comment: and yet if I swap the numbers around so its reversed, the toggle effect works?

Comment: Would the $(.homepage').fadeTo(500,1); need a callback function?

Comment: I think setting .homepage to hide with jquery would be an issue because that has the effect of setting the css on .homepage to display: none. When the code tries to re-adjust the opacity the display is likely still set to display:none. If you do a $('.homepage').show() right before the line of code $('.homepage').fadeTo(500, 1); it may very well solve the issue. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi tellez, the .homepage isn't set to hide with Jquery or CSS, its completely visible upon loading the website, the .sub1 is set to .hide with Jquery , the additional code you mentioned did not do anything for me, thank you though I really do appreciate your efforts, this is very frustrating. If I can and if you want to, I will attach the site files, it might show you what I'm trying to achieve, but will lack any imagery.